# Camera preview freezes after screen lock

Tags: java, android, android-activity, camera

The custom camera app I've written stops giving the preview after the screen locks (by pushing lock butten or waiting for a couple of minutes). I don't get an exception, which makes it quite difficult to find the problem.

Does the android screen lock (if that's the correct term) pauses/halts/... my App (activity)?

If this were the case, could the cause be my onPause/onResume methods? Or is another cause mor likely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you need to stop the camere preview in `onPause` and resume it in `onResume`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I faced same problem and fixed it using following steps:

1. I created my camera preview and added it to the container FrameLayout in onResume() of the parent activity. Something like:

   ```
   public void onResume{
       super.onResume();
       mCamera = Camera.open();
       if(null != mCamera){
           mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
           mPreview = new CameraOverlay(getActivity(), mCamera);
           frLyParent.addView(mPreview);
       }
   }
   ```
2. I removed the view in onPause(). This fixes the freeze.

   ```
   public void onPause(){
       super.onPause();
       if(null != mCamera){
           mCamera.release();
           mCamera = null;
       }
       frLyParent.removeView(mPreview);
       mPreview = null;
   }
   ```

where CameraOverlay() is the class which extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback. Do let me know if you need that implementation.

Comment: Hi itsviks . Could you please update what you tried to wrote at step 2. Thanks.

Comment: You are a genius man! thank you! I didn't use the frLyParen.removeView(mPreview), that's fundamental!

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi me too, I've been searching for almost 2 days until I found this line `frLyParen.removeView(mPreview)` :)

Comment: I hope it's not too long after this was posted, but could someone just send exactly what the implementation was?  I've been struggling with this for 12 hours straight now!

Comment: @SimonT I based my implementation off [Google's suggestion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) but added `preview.removeView(mPreview)` before `preview.addView(mPreview)` in `onCreate`. I think the old view was sticking around and causing the appearance of the preview being frozen (even though I did get frames from the camera).

Answer (score 7):

here is mine, it does work :-)

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            surface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        try {
            surface.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.removeCallback(this);
            camera.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In `onResume()` method add this line :

```
surfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In `onPaused()` method add this line :

```
surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, because it nails the problem.

Comment: I have +1'ed it but it wasn't me that made the question.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, I used a modification of this and it works for me too

I added `mPreview.removeView(mPreview.mSurfaceView);` in `onpause()`, and `mPreview.addView(mPreview.mSurfaceView);` in `onResume()` before opening the camera.

I also deleted `addView(mSurfaceView);` in the preview class.